# Terraform resource property dependent on creation of resource

Tags: terraform

Often, I've found myself in the scenario where I want to create a resource with Terraform and want to set, for example, an environment variable on this resource which is only known at a later stage, when the resource is created.

Let's say I want to create a `google_cloud_run_service` and want to set an environment variable in the container, that represents the url from which the app can be approached:

```
resource "google_cloud_run_service" "test_app" {
  name = "test-app"
  location = var.region

  template {
    spec {
      containers {
        image = "gcr.io/myimage:latest"

        env {
          name = "CURRENT_HOST"
          value = google_cloud_run_service.test_app.status[0].url
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This however is not allowed, as the service is not yet created. Is there a way to accomplish this?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Cloud Run so I can't give a specific answer but generally-speaking if an object needs to know properties about itself then that object must fetch them on its own; does Cloud Run provide an API for a service to ask directly for its own URL, rather than expecting that to be passed from Terraform?

Comment: I understand your approach, that's a way to solve the problem. However, I think that an application should be agnostic of the runtime environment. Hence, I don't want to implement a call to the Cloud Run API in order to find the url. That's why I'd do it with an environment variable. There's also no data resource for Cloud Run available in Terraform, so it seems that this is not possible here.

Comment: Cloud Run itself doesn't seem to support what you want to do here, regardless of whether Terraform were in play: the environment variables for a [Service](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/reference/rest/v1/namespaces.services#Service) are submitted as part of creating that service, and the service doesn't have a URL until it's created. Cloud Run may offer a way to declare in your "spec" that you want it to pass the URL to the container somehow, but Terraform is constrained by what the underlying API supports and so can't really help with this problem.

Comment: Yeah, I see indeed. Well even while it wasn't what I was hoping for, it does answer the question. Thanks for your help!